# Percentage Calculation in Spotfire

Tags: percentage, spotfire

[image: DataSet_Image]

This is the data that i've in Spotfire like this and trying to arrive at a percent calculation with the logic.

The formatting messed up the first time i posted the question.

Percentage for Instagram: `(Count of Instagram) / (Count of all Social network)`

Can you please help me with the calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it with a cross table:

- set "Question# 1" as row header
- enter this expression as value: `Count() / Count() over (All([Axis.Rows]))`

[image]

Comment: Hi Mate, The formatting got messed up when i entered data manually. Can you please look into the attachment pic and help me with the calculation?

Comment: @VijayR this answer does just what you asked, in a cross table. If you want it in a calculated column, you just need to specify that.